# Post FromBody not working without trailing slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, nswag

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web API project that utilizes NSwag to get Swagger functionality. The problem is that when I use the SwaggerUI to test the API, the FromBody parameter is not working. However when I use Postman with the same body and application/json selected for the header (as in SwaggerUi), everything works.
In the debugger I noticed that the requests from Postman have a trailing slash, while the requests from SwaggerUi dont.

Here is the action from the controller:

```
[HttpPost("")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, typeof(BlobItem))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] BlobItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return this.BadRequest("the item is null");
    }

    var blobItem = await BlobHelpers.PostBlobItemAync(this.container, item);

    return this.CreatedAtRoute("GetBlobInfo", new { blobName = item.Name }, blobItem);
}
```

Postman -> item is filled
SwaggerUi -> item is null

---

I tried adding a trailing slash to the default route in Startup

```
app.UseSwaggerUi(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, new SwaggerUiSettings()
{
    DefaultUrlTemplate = "{controller}/{action}/{id}/",
    DefaultPropertyNameHandling = NJsonSchema.PropertyNameHandling.CamelCase,
});
```

without success and also

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.AppendTrailingSlash = true);
```

in Startup.ConfigureServices without success, meaning that the request still does not have the trailing slash through SwaggerUi.

---

**How do I enforce trailing slashes or can I do something else to make sure that the FromBody parameter is working?**

Comment: The problem is not due to a trailing slash or lack thereof. That's a red herring. If the value is coming through as null, then that means that it is not being submitted in correct format. In particular, `FromBody` means your request body needs to have a content type of something like `application/json`, or `application/xml`. If you're trying to do x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, then you should be using `FromForm` instead.

Comment: Is it a problem with your web api controller, the generated spec or swagger ui?

Comment: Have you tried [HttpPost()] without empty string?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Both set the content type to application/json.

Comment: @RicoSuter I think the problem is with the generated spec or the ui. The controller works, because it works with Postman.  
I tried HttpPost without empty string.

Comment: @RicoSuter The generated client from NSwag is working in another .Net project, although the missing trailing slash. So something else is off here. I think SwaggerUi is the problem then.

Comment: Strange, I will soon upgrade NSwag to Swagger UI 3.x (currently 2.x), maybe this fixes the problem...

Comment: @RicoSuter sounds good. Do you have a timeframe for SwaggerUi 3? I just introduced members of my development team to NSwag and I think they would love that :)

Comment: Its already working in a feature branch: https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/tree/redoc-and-new-swagger-ui

Comment: Now merged into mastrr, UseSwaggerUi3() and UseSwaggerReDoc()

Comment: Btw: Have you checked chris' comment? If the transmitted json is invalid, the obj is null... try using a simpler object to test this...

Comment: The item is just three strings. And the exact same json is working in Postman @RicoSuter.  
The current Master is not released yet, right?

Comment: Ah ok, then its probably really a problem with Swagger UI... No its not released yet

Comment: The NSwag v11.7.2 release build is running now, should be available soon

Comment: Is this issue resolved?